Can't import javax.swing in Eclipse (even with new jdk)
Can't import javax.swing in Eclipse 2024-09 for a JOptionPane (or any other swing import).
I've tried clean install eclipse with the default jre, I've uninstalled it and installed it two other times, one with java jdk 23 and another one with jdk 21, I've checked the installed JREs section in the Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs section every time and also checked the installed libraries in the Project > Properties > Java Build Path section as said in other questions. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've been troubleshooting this all day, need help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have and the full complete error messages you get based on the source code. Add the error messages as text as well as a screenshot from the import lines (but do not add only the screenshot).

Do you have a module-info.java in your src folder?

Search Stack Overflow before posting.
